# Adding modifier to View's body

Tags: swiftui

Given I have a simple `View` like:

```
public struct MyView: View {
  public var body: some View {
     Text("My text 1")
     Text("My text 1")
  }
}
```

Is there an elegant way of setting a modifier on the `View`'s body (such as setting `AccessibilityIdentifier`) straight in this struct without having to do this in the class that embeds `MyView` or creating another View layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way is to wrap the content of the `body` in a `Group`

```
public struct MyView: View {
  public var body: some View {
      Group {
          Text("My text 1")
          Text("My text 1")
      }
      .font(.title)
  }
}
```